# What is the game where you have to identify a person based on their features?

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to find the name of a game that I played when I was a child. In it, there were a large number of characters in various costumes. The object of the game was either to guess a target character or guess opponents' characters. I do not remember the exact mechanics by which you played and figured out which character you were looking for. Some key features:

- The characters were photographed models in costumes, not drawn;
- I would have played this game in the early 80s and I recall the box looking rather old, so I would place this game most likely in the 1970s if not 1960s;
- I cannot recall if there was an actual board, but it came in a long cardboard box similar to those that held board games at the time;
- I remember there were cards, and it is possible that each player was dealt one as "their character."
- I vaguely recall that the cards were larger than standard game cards, possibly 4x6 or 5x7 inches.
- It had a short name like "Clue" but obviously I'm not thinking of Clue.
- Five or six players could play this game at once.

**Can anyone identify the game I am so imperfectly recalling?**

Comment: That sounds like Guess Who. Most editions have drawn characters rather than photographs, but there are a lot of editions, so I wouldn't be surprised if an early one had photos.

Comment: I'm sort of new here, but should answers be in comments? It is not Guess Who, and in fact watching my nieces play Guess Who is what got me thinking about this older game. I will add to my question that at least five or six people could play at once, unlike Guess Who.

Comment: Ah, but it didn't answer your question, did it?  But it helped you improve the question, which is what comments are for.  I'll admit that there's a bit of a grey area here,  but I didn't have proof that it actually fulfilled the criteria of your question.  If I knew of a photo edition for sure I would have submitted it as an answer.  (Probably. I was pretty tired last night)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you did. Lucky for you it *wasn't* Guess Who. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing «Whosit?» (1976)

[Whosit? on Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2406/whosit)
[image: Board image from BoardGameGeek]

Comment: Yep, this is it. The name and photo totally rang a bell, and I now recall that the board was only for reference and didn't have pieces on it. That's probably why I was unsure if there was a board. Thanks Robert!

Comment: "Whosit!" was reimplemented recently by Restoration Games as "Dinosaur Tea Party", resulting in a game that has less of that 70s chic but also less of that 70s stereotyping.